# Find the time at which the particle has traveled $14$ units

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If a particle follows the path defined by $$r(t) = (2t^{3/2},2t+1, \sqrt{5} t )$$ and starts at $t=0$, at what time will the particle have traveled a total of $14$ units ?

Comment: well, I tried to find the derivative of r(t) but I am not sure if that is the right way to start

Comment: That is in fact the first step. So you've found the velocity vector. Now find the magnitude of the velocity vector, which gives you the speed as a function of time.

Comment: and what is the next step ?

Comment: @user131040: what is the relationship between speed and distance traveled, in terms of time?

Comment: I am not sure if I am getting it, could you be more clear please

Comment: @user131040, suppose you are travelling at a constant $50$ mph for $3$ hours.  Then you have traveled $150$ miles.  How might you go about finding how far you have traveled if your speed wasn't constant?  I.e. if you were given some graph of your speed vs. time.

Comment: the acceleration ?

Comment: I just edited the equation $$r(t) = (2t^{3/2},2t+1, \sqrt{5} t )$$

Answer (score 3):

The formula is a mild generalization of the one for arclength in two dimensions. Take the derivatives, find the sum of their squares, take the square root, and integrate.

We get "lucky," the sum of the squares of the derivatives is simple, it is $9t+9$. So if we travel from time $0$ to time $\tau$, the path length is
$$\int_0^\tau \sqrt{9t+9}\,dt.$$
Integrate, set the result equal to $14$, and solve for $\tau$.

Comment: Why could we not just evaluate $\sqrt{r_x^2+r_y^2+r_z^2}$ and set this equal to 14, and solve for $t$ (since distance is just the norm of displacement)?

Comment: @alexqwx:  Your suggestion correctly finds the straight line distance from the beginning to the end. But we took a path that is not a straight line. It is a matter of interpretation. If I go from $A$ to $B$, a distance of $200$ km, and then back again, is the total distance travelled $400$, or is it $0$?

Answer (score 0):

The distance $d(t)$ traveled between time $t=0$ and time $t=t$ is given by:

$$d^2(t)=|r(t)-r(0)|^2 = t(4t^2+4t+5)$$

Setting

$$d^2(t)=14^2$$ we obtain:

$$t(4t^2+4t+5)=14^2$$

The only real solution of this equation is given by:

$$t=\frac{1}{6}(-2-11\omega^{-1}+\omega)=3.25119...$$
$$\omega=\left(5329+18(87653)^{1/2}\right)^{1/3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\vec{r}(t)=\left(2t^\frac32,2t+1,\sqrt{5}t\right)$$
You've got a vector of the position $r$ in terms of $t$. What you want to do next is find the velocity vector in terms of $t$, because "14 units" is the area swept by the magnitude of the velocity vector from $t=0$. This is done by simply differentiating:
$$\vec{v}(t)=\left(3t^\frac12,2,\sqrt 5\right)$$

Now you want to find the function for the magnitude of this vector. You probably know how to do that, for vector $\vec{A}=(a, b, c)$, the magnitude is just $\big|\vec{A}\big|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$. Hence:

$$\begin{align}\biggr|\vec{v}(t)\biggr|&=\sqrt{\left(3t^\frac12\right)^2+\left(2\right)^2+\left(\sqrt 5\right)^2} \\ &=\sqrt{9t+4+5}\end{align}$$

Now the distance covered is the integral of that. This is a magnitude so it won't be negative, but you have just velocity, then you'd take the absolute value of it (for distance traveled rather than displacement).

Hence we've got:
$$\int_{t=0}^{t=t_0} \sqrt{9t+9}=14$$

That evaluates to:
$$\frac{1}{13.5}(9t+9)^\frac32\Biggr|_{t=0}^{t=t_0}=14$$

You find that $t_0=3$